# Matrix as a force component?

Tags: angular-momentum, quantum-spin

In Griffiths' *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics*, he briefly introduces the Stern-Gerlach experiment with the following example.

[image]

The magnetic field is
$$ \mathbf{B} = -\alpha x \mathbf{\hat{x}} + \left(B_0 + \alpha z\right)\mathbf{\hat{z}}, $$
where $\alpha$ is a small deviation from uniform magnetic field, and an $x$ component is added to satisfy $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B} = 0$.

Using
$$ \mathbf{F} = \nabla\left(\mathbf{\mu} \cdot \mathbf{B}\right) $$
and
$$ \mathbf{\mu} = \gamma \mathbf{S}, $$
where $\gamma$ is the gyromagnetic ratio, we find that (averaging over time, the influence of $S_x$ is equal to zero due to Larmor precession)
$$ \mathbf{F} = \gamma\alpha S_z \mathbf{\hat{z}} = \frac{\gamma\alpha\hbar}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\mathbf{\hat{z}} . $$
Now I don't get what it means for the component of a vector to be a matrix, or if it makes sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote down is the *operator* for z-projection of the force, using the operator for angular momentum.

The force itself is still a scalar, where it's magnitude is the expectation value, e.g., $\langle\uparrow|\hat{\mathbf{F}}|\uparrow\rangle = \frac{\gamma \alpha \hbar}{2}$.

Comment: I suppose $\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|#1\rangle} \ket{\uparrow}$ means the spin-up state with respect to the $z$ axis?

Comment: Yes. In the representation you use, it would correspond to the $[1, 0]^T$ state vector.